# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity when using custom subdomain url in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using `devise gem` for authentication. earlier it was working fine when I ran `rails` in `localhost:3000`. but when I edited my `/etc/hosts` and added

`127.0.0.1       tenant1.lv.me` to my hosts file

I'm not able to login getting "**Can't verify CSRF token authenticity**"

any idea !!

Comment: which browser? all browsers? rails version and devise version would also be helpful

Comment: chrome, firefox , rails `5.1.4`  devise `4.4.0`

Comment: can you share your  config.session_store ?

Comment: Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store,
  key: '_igloo_session',
  secure: Rails.env.production?

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve your problem?